# Word Document Error

Tags: document-library

I am getting the following error when trying to open a word document in Shared Documents in  one of the portal:

> Viewing of .doc files has been disabled in Word Web App. Contact your
>   site administrator for further help.

Is this the permission issue?

Comment: are you able to view other documents such as docx, pptx, xlsx, etc when uploaded to the same document library?

Comment: Yes am able to view other documents

Comment: When I try to change .doc to .docx..am getting the below error                   "  Word Web App cannot open this document for viewing because of an unexpected error. To view this document, open it in Microsoft Word."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to view other Office documents as you stated in your comment then the problem is only with viewing Word files. Your OWA settings should be fine.

Now open your Central Admin > Application Management > Manage Services on Server and check if **Word Viewing Service** is created and running.

At your client side ensure to check the document title bar for "[Compatibility Mode]".

Go: File > Info, and then click Convert.

Save the document as Word Document (.docx) before uploading to a document library.

Comment: Problem with the version of the file,I have converted it to the latest version, now it is working fine.Thanks all.